# How to get saved value in sqlite database to list in Android?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am trying to get saved values in a list. I am creating anotepad and I want when anybody open notepad every saved list display on homepage in a list.

I have successfully saved the value in a database but when I am trying to get a value in a list it is giving full string value like this "com.todo.task.activity@4106a690" in every single row.

I think problem is in my database getlist() method please check:

```
 public List<TaskDetailsActivity> GetAddTaskLists() {
     List<TaskDetailsActivity> TaskLists = new ArrayList<TaskDetailsActivity>();

     // Select All Query
     String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_TASKLISTS;
     SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
     Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

     // looping through all rows and adding to list
     if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
         do {
             TaskDetailsActivity tasks = new TaskDetailsActivity();
             tasks.settaskLists_ID(cursor.getString(0));
             tasks.settasklists_Title(cursor.getString(1));

             // Adding Doc to list
             TaskLists.add(tasks);
         } while (cursor.moveToNext());
     }

    // return Doc list
     return TaskLists;      
    }
```

Here I am calling database method like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ListView list_tasklistname = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_tasklistname);
    TaskManager_Database db = new TaskManager_Database(getApplicationContext());
    list = db.GetAddTaskLists();
    ArrayAdapter<TaskDetailsActivity> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<TaskDetailsActivity>(getApplicationContext(), 
                                                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    list_tasklistname.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Please let me know what is the error. Thanks

Comment: have u open/close your database

Comment: @DixitPatel  yeah I did..

Answer (score 0):

You are getting object representation of objects been added to `ListView`...

In your case you should return data in `cursor.getString(1)` for adapter input param i.e. String array...... i.e list must be a string array or ArrayList... if you know what I mean..

check out this [sample for ref](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your `TaskDetailsActivity` class should define a `toString()` method that returns whatever you want to display for that row.